# Difference between 'gamer' and 'player'?

Tags: grammar, meaning, american-english, nouns

I saw a sentence today:

> Back in the last century, ***gamers*** were sometimes known to take advantage of ***players*** with slow (as in dialup) links; an opponent could be eliminated literally before he or she could respond.

(*An Introduction to Computer Networks*, 2nd edition, Doral, P161)

Why does the author use both 'gamers' and 'players'? I wonder whether 'gamer' and 'player' have other meanings. Thanks a lot.

Comment: **gamers** are a subset of **players**.

Comment: Hello Eason,  Please **give the source for your quote**  Where did you read this?  Provide a link to the internet site

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence you have given “gamers” means “people who play video games”(habitually, or as a hobby), while “players” refers to “people who are currently playing a game”.

Because there are two distinct groups in the sentence; the gamers who take advantage, and the people with slow dial-up; it’s natural to draw a distinction, either by using different words or you could be explicit by saying:

> […]gamers were sometimes known to take advantage of **other gamers** with slow (as in dialup) links[…]

But this doesn’t quite sound as good as the original example. A small amount of context is also lost: by using “players”, you emphasise that they are taking advantage of them *while playing against them*, and not in some other way, say by secretly joining their team chats and finding out their strategy before the game.

You could also swap “gamers” for another kind of player to make a similar sentence:

> **Footballers** are known to take advantage of players who take their eye off the ball.

Comment: So is "player" just equal to "other gamers"?  I saw another explanation saying "gamers" are close to "hardcore players," a subset of players. I mean are they just used for distinction or actually they have different meanings subtly? Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @EasonWang in this sentence I would read it as having that implication only a very small amount: after all, the “gamers” play enough to recognise the players who have bad connections, so there’s a small element of being “hardcore”.

Comment: @EasonWang outside of this sentence, the word “Gamer” (particularly when written with a capital “G”) can have a whole host of additional implications. Some of these are neutral like “plays games a lot”, but other uses can be quite exclusionary. For a whole rabbit hole on that, you can read more about “Gamergate”. Personally I wouldn’t really use the term any more, especially since smartphones made basically everyone play video games.